# Regex for matching url path but without params, first group match

Tags: regex

Let's say I have urls like these

1. `https://example.com/link`
2. `https://example.com/link?code=1234`
3. `https://example.com/link/with/longer/path`

What I need is to match accordingly:

1. `link`
2. `link`
3. `link/with/longer/path`

This regex: `^(?:[^/]*(?:/(?:/[^/]*/?)?)?([^?]+)(?:\??.+)?)$`  is able to group a path, but because of a tool I use, I need to match preciesliy just that one group - this regex matches whole URLs.

Can I make it match just the first group? Or maybe there is something smarter to do it?

Comment: The `(?<=(?<!/)/)(?!/)[^?]+` regex [might work](https://regex101.com/r/IWjhZR/1) if lookarounds are supported.

Comment: It does work indeed, want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=(?<!/)/)(?!/)[^?]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IWjhZR/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=(?<!/)/)` - a positive lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `/` char immediately to the left of the current location that is not immediately preceded with another `/` char (the check if performed with a `(?<!/)` negative lookbehind)
- `(?!/)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `/` char immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^?]+` - one or more chars other than a `?` char.